# Can I use Xcode as a simple text editor?

Tags: xcode, text-editor

Okay ... This may be a ridiculous question.  (I'm still getting used to Mac.)  I really like the auto fill-in-ahead predictive typing feature of Xcode.

Can I use it to simply edit files laying around different locations on my hard drive?   I do not really want to create a project or anything (unless by **PROJECT** I mean *simply loads several files, that are not related to each other, but that I may want to jump back and forth in editing them* - I do not want to create a project from files that need to be compiled or anything).

If so, what's the best way to get started?  When you open XCode, it asked a lot of wizard questions to get things set up.  How would I simply get started to edit 5 or so files at a time ... where I might want to switch back and forth between them - and they are not in the same directory?

All I want to do is simply make changes and save them, make more changes and save again, repeat.   Kind of like holding a lot of shell scripts that communicate with each other.

Okay ... so I know this was a silly question - but Xcode is so intimidating for newbies.   Sometimes, one needs a place to just get started and I haven't found that yet.

Comment: You're right, it IS a ridiculous question (:

Comment: did you create a new text file and try to open it with xcode?

Comment: Okay ... from Finder, I went a file that I wanted to open, right clicked, and selected the Open With option.  I navigated to XCode, and clicked that.  It opened a tutorial iOS project that I worked on previously.  The original file was not opened by XCode.   Weird.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to open the Xcode text editor on a single file from the command line.

```
open -a Xcode.app filename.txt
```

If you're going to use this a lot, you might consider making an alias in your ~/.bashrc.

```
alias xc="open -a Xcode.app"
```

As of Xcode 6, you cannot open a directory this way, as it will give you an error message stating that directories must be opened as part of a project. If you provide more than one file on the command line, Xcode appears to create a temporary project containing the files you provided. You can add files and folders to the temporary project, but there doesn't seem to be a way to save the temp project for use later.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a file in Xcode, you can also use `xed`.

As the man page says:

> xed -- Xcode text editor invocation tool.

You can simply call `xed [file]` to launch Xcode editor.

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Worth knowing about [xcode-select](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-select-managing-multiple-versions-of-xcode.html) in conjunction with this.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ is the way to go. Xcode was never meant to be used as a general text editor.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't know that there wasn't a Mac port for Notepad++. Use TextWrangler instead.

Comment: I do not think you can get Notepad++ for mac. Also that does not have the autofill in feature that he likes about xcode... not that he should use xcode though!

Comment: @Joel Wow, I assumed that there's a Mac port for Notepad++. My mistake.

Comment: @RichWalt Sorry, I meant TextWrangler. And yes, it's free and capable of having several files open.

Comment: Okay ... from this youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kSsqic-aKo ... which I'm still watching, TextWrangle looks a lot like UltraEdit on Windows.  (BTW, UltraEdit is not as smooth for Mac - just saying ... not to mention, UE is not free. )   Looks like I'll be getting TextWrangle.   :-)

Comment: @David, yeah I just got a mac and was shocked by that too, I use textwrangler (also I did not downrate you)

Comment: @Joel Glad we're on the same boat :)